# Creating a column with 0,1,0.5 values instead of a boolean in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Consider this dataframe:

```
id   Name   Score   
314  John    100    
345  Sara    200
355  Zack    200
333  Harry    50
334  Chad     50
331  Newton  100
```

I want to assign custom values to a new operator column based on the score , so if one score is less than the next, it is a 1, if it is greater than 0, and if it stays same then a 0.5. This is what I want this to look like:

```
id   Name   Score  Operator
314  John    100      1
345  Sara    200     0.5
355  Zack    200      0
333  Harry    50     0.5
334  Chad     50      1    
331  Newton  100     NAN
```

I have tried a combination of difference and boolean columns but it doesn't give any access to move away from a binary approach

Comment: `df.assign(m = [0 if x>y else 1 if x<y else 0.5 if x==y else float('Nan') for x,y in zip(df.Score,df.Score.shift(-1))])` can also work

Comment: thanks man, any references u know for detailed manipulations like these?

Comment: I used an if else statement nothing more. Look at it. you already know if else statement, with the logic being `this if TRUE else that`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, set up your conditions:

```
prev = df.Score.shift(-1)
c1, c2, c3 = df.Score.lt(prev), df.Score.eq(prev), df.Score.gt(prev)
```

Now use `numpy.select`:

```
out = df.assign(out=np.select([c1, c2, c3], [1, 0.5, 0], np.nan))

    id    Name  Score  out
0  314    John    100  1.0
1  345    Sara    200  0.5
2  355    Zack    200  0.0
3  333   Harry     50  0.5
4  334    Chad     50  1.0
5  331  Newton    100  NaN
```

---

Here's another solution that's just for fun (only works if you never have a difference less than `0.5`):

```
df.Score.diff(-1).mul(-1).add(0.5).clip(0, 1)
```

```
0    1.0
1    0.5
2    0.0
3    0.5
4    1.0
5    NaN
Name: Score, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Any references to learn these manipulations? I've tried tons of pandas books but they all give very basic intros and skip on

Comment: I personally rely on the documentation more than anything.  But I've also learned quite a bit from SO